# Generic design for importing data via XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am designing a generic solution to import object data from an XML. In my application the class structure is like following:

```
class MyObject
{
    public string ID { get; private set; }

    // This may contain large set of values.
    public Dictionary<string, OtherClass> ObjectData { get; set; };

    public MyObject()
    {}
}

class OtherClass
{
    public string SubProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string SubProperty2 { get; set; }
    public string SubProperty3 { get; set; }
}
```

There can be many other classes similar to `MyObject` which may have properties of different types that needs to be imported.

Schema design I've in my mind would generate following XML structure:

```
<BlobData DataType="MyObjectType">
  <DataValues UniqueID="MyObjectID" Property="SerializedPropertyName">
    <DataValue PointID="Point1" SubProperty="SubProperty1">Value1.1</DataValue>
    <DataValue PointID="Point2" SubProperty="SubProperty1">Value1.2</DataValue>
    <DataValue PointID="Point3" SubProperty="SubProperty1">Value1.3</DataValue>
    <DataValue PointID="Point1" SubProperty="SubProperty2">Value2.1</DataValue>
    <DataValue PointID="Point2" SubProperty="SubProperty2">Value2.2</DataValue>
    <DataValue PointID="Point3" SubProperty="SubProperty2">Value2.3</DataValue>
  </DataValues>
</BlobData>
```

I am still confused whether this structure is sufficient for any future work that may come up. Please suggest if you have any experience of designing similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with different data (which is in Xml format), I have done the following in my work:

- Make sure each xml data is backed by XSD (Schema)
- You can then use XSD.exe to convert the schema into CS
- In C#, you work with that data Model directly (by Deserializing it from Xml to C# using `XmlSerializer`)
- That way you mainly concentrate on your DataModel (C# equivalent) rather than parsing the Xml elements and attributes

It doesnt work in all scenarios, but might work in most where schema is backward compatible

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of all of your classes are similar (e.g. ID + some sub-properties), I would use a list/set/other collection instead of the dictionary.  The collection would contain a general subproperty type/class that has three values: Id (PointID?), the name of the sub-property and the value.

Use dictionary if the key to map from is unique (it is unclear to me what is your string key in your example)

Comment: Thanks for you response. Not all classes have same structure. In this example I've used dictionary for quick access to OtherClass by using Key. Yes, they are unique and they will be for other classes as well. Actually each class will have responsibility to interpret the data for its use. For example, currently all the attributes are necessary because the MyObject class has dictionary. PointIDs -> Keys and SubProperties -> properties of OtherClass. But it may be possible that some class has simple structure where value can be directly specified without any attributes <DataValue>val</DataValue>

Comment: Continued.. which means value is directly associated with SerializedPropertyName

Comment: If the classes are different enough, you are better off creating specific classes for each possible types you can encounter in the XML